# FieldArrays in a separate component

Tags: redux-form

I'm using redux-form v6.0.1. I created a component similar to that from documentation example: http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/examples/fieldArrays/

Following the code below from the example, can I move all the fields and action buttons rendering inside `<li key={index}>` to the separate component to enforce that bind or arrow functions are not used (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)?

```
const renderMembers = ({ fields }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Member</button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((member, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Member"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
        <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.firstName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="First Name"/>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.lastName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Last Name"/>
        <FieldArray name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies}/>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Thank you, 
Darek.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I move all the fields and action buttons rendering inside `<li key={index}>` to the separate component to enforce that bind or arrow functions are not used?

Sure. Have you tried it and run into a problem?

Comment: I wanted to use:
        ```<Fields names={[`${member}.firstname`, `${member}.lastName`]} component={RenderNames} index={index} />```

but couldn't get to the fields in `RenderNames` component like documentation says

Answer (score 0):

I have a very complicated form with a lot of arrays fields inside, and I know that arrow functions are very bad for performance.
Thats why instead of

```
{fields.map((member, index) =>
  <li key={index}>
    <button
      type="button"
      title="Remove Member"
      onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
    <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
    <Field
      name={`${member}.firstName`}
      type="text"
      component={renderField}
      label="First Name"/>
    <Field
      name={`${member}.lastName`}
      type="text"
      component={renderField}
      label="Last Name"/>
    <FieldArray name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies}/>
  </li>
)}
```

I tried somethind like that:

```
{fields.map((member, index) =>
  <li key={index}>
    <Fields 
      names={`[${member}.firstname`, `${member}.lastName`]} 
      component={RenderNames}
      index={index}
    />
  </li>
)}

const RenderNames = (fields) => {
  const removeItem = () => {
    fields.remove(index);
  }

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      title="Remove Member"
      onClick={removeItem} 
    />

    // how to get 'firstname' and 'lastname' here?
  )
}
```

but couldn't get fields object in a way described in documentation